# Multiple interactions in a regression using the same dummy with high correlation

Tags: interaction, multicollinearity

Y= alpha+ b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b3* x3 +b4*x4 + b5*dummy1*x1+b6*dummy1*x2 + b7*dummy1*x3 +b8*dummy1*x4

I run the correlation between all the regression variables and I found that all variables that are multiplied by dummy1 are highly correlated (correlation can reach up to 0.77). is this normal when I use many interaction terms based on the same dummy or should I resort to something to solve multicolinearity (such as orthogonalizing dummy1*x1 on dummy1*x2 etc....)

Comment: Do you mean x1 and x2 are correlated or do you mean the interaction terms? If the latter I would have thought this is quite likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: the more the correlations among the interaction variables are different from the ones among the original ($X$) variables, the more this is due to the multiplication of the $X$'s for the same dummy variable (to build the interaction ones).

**Long answer**:
The four variables
$Y_1=dummy1*X_1$; $Y_2=dummy1*X_2$; $Y_3=dummy1*X_3$; $Y_4=dummy1*X_4$ are all equal to $0$ when $dummy1=0$, and are equal to the $X$ variables when $dummy1=1$.Let's say $dummy1=0$ $k\%$ of the times. You have that $k\%$ of the times the four variables are equal. The more this $k$ is close to $0$, the more often the $Y$ variables will be equal to their $X$ variables, and thus the correlation among the $Y$'s will approach the one among the $X$'s. On the contrary, the higher the value of $k$, the more the correlation among $Y$ could depart from the one of $X$. In which direction? It depends on where $0$ stands in the distribution of the $X$'s (and also on the association between the dummy and the $X$'s variables, but I don't investigate this issue further here to keep things simple). If, for example, the $X$'s are all above $0$, the $Y$'s will either all be equal to $0$ (when the dummy equals $0$), or all above $0$ (when the dummy is $1$). This implies that the $k\%$ lowest values for each $Y$ will coincide with the lowest values for the other $Y$'s (or, if you prefer, the $(100-k)\%$ highest values for each $Y$ will coincide with the highest values for the other $Y$'s). Suppose $k=50\%$: for all $Y$'s, the half of the low-value observations will be the same (and the value will be $0$ for each $Y$ for all of them). This implies that also the half of the high-value observations will be the same (even if, in this case, there will typically be variability in the values and, for example, the highest value for $Y_1$ needs not come from the same observation showing the highest value for $Y_2$). This will obviously make the correlation increase.

However, to be more precise about the effect of multiplying a group of variables for the same dummy variable on their correlations, more information would be needed on the joint distribution of the dummy variable and the $X$'s. I just described a possible scenario above, many others could be built...